# How to get all subpages from the current mainpage

Tags: wordpress

Example, I've got this menu, and added to the pages About and Vacancies subpages, and added them in the page settings

```
Home
About
-- History
-- Photo's
Vacancies
-- Front-end developer
-- Full-stack developer
Contact
```

How can I get the current main page when I'm on a subpage? For example I'm on the main page About, than I want a list of all subpages (History and Photo's in this example)

The same for page vacancies, when I'm on the main page I want to get a list of all children pages.

I tried below, but then I get all pages of cpt 'page'. Not the children's that I need. Can anyone help please? :)

```
    <?php
    global $post;

    $args = array(
        'child_of'          => $post->ID,
        'post_type'         => 'page',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'depth'             => 1,
        'orderby'           => 'date',
    );

    $parent = new WP_Query($args); ?>

    <?php if ($parent->have_posts()) : ?>

        <div class="submenu-pages">

            <ul>
                <?php while ($parent->have_posts()) : $parent->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <a class="submenu-pages__link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: You are asking two different questions 1) How can I get the current main page when I'm on a subpage? 2) when I'm on the main page I want to get a list of all children pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`child_of` (and `depth`) are used with `wp_list_pages()`; not as part of the arguments for `WP_Query` class.

So all you need to do to make your code works (the `new WP_Query()` part), is use `post_parent` to retrieve posts that are children of the specified parent:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID, // use post_parent and not child_of
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
);
```

Comment: PS: [Here's the documentation for `wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/), and if using `$post->ID` above doesn't work, then try with `get_queried_object_id()`. :)

Comment: So close! Thank you for the answer!